# Handling files by UserForm without being stuck behind

Tags: excel, vba

I try to start Workbook, scan data, to add or change, save and close.
The problem is that when the Workbook opens, it takes the focus, and the UserForm moves to the background. The function "Workbooks (.........). Activate" is not working, to get focus
Even "Application.Run" does not do the job

I would appreciate any suggestion
Thank you!

An example of my problem:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    MyFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files(*.xls*),excel", 1, "Select file", "open", False)
    Workbooks.Open (MyFilename)

    For i = Len(MyFilename) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(MyFilename, i, 1) = "\" Then MyFilename = Mid(MyFilename, i + 1, Len(MyFilename) - i): Exit For
    Next

    Label1.Caption = Workbooks(MyFilename).Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    Label2.Caption = Workbooks(MyFilename).Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
    Label3.Caption = Workbooks(MyFilename).Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just put `Me.Activate` line at the end of your `CommandButton1_Click()` sub.

or

Put the line `Workbooks("UserFormWorkbook.xls").Activate` in the `Workbook_Activate` event of the Workbook which is opened by the `UserFormWorkbook`.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Workbooks("UserFormWorkbook.xls").Activate
End sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer!
I tried, but it's not working. Probably I lack the basic concepts or there is something wrong?
I appreciate the effort
I would be happy to hear more suggestions If it is possible
Good Day!

Comment: @chaim add some more explanation. I run your code. It opened another workbook than first workbook have got focus; activate events of both workbooks had been fired also.

Comment: I appreciate the patience and the detailed explanation!
The idea to add the new macro workbook is a great idea if it's just a file type with Macro,
So in the meantime I have used with the first idea,
I added at the end of the line code similar to your idea
     TextBox1.SetFocus
And works great
Thank you!!!